# Installing Entity Framework in Visual Studio Code Extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, entity-framework-core

I am installing the Entity Framework in VSCODE Extension using the following link:http://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet.html but got the error while running the command "dotnet ef --help" from command prompt  which verifies that whether Entity Framework installed or not. Error: assembly specified in the dependencies manifest was not found -- package: 'microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.abstractions', version: '1.0.0', path: 'lib/netstandard1.3/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll'. I would really appriciate if you help me in this task.
 Thanks

Comment: Have you had any success in resolving this issue yet ? For info an issue has been opened on github for this : https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/6564

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Tools » NuGet Package Manager » Manage NuGet Packages For Solution
2. Ensure that Browse is selected and type "entityframeworkcore" into the search box
3. Click on the provider that you want to install. SQL Server is selected in this case.
4. Check the project that you want to install the package into, then click Install
5. Review the changes that are about to be made to your project (unless you have previously ticked the box to prevent this dialog from appearing)

it is in https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/efcore/how-to-get
go there you will find more details